# How to provide an AccountData type implementing some trait?

Tags: accountdata

In pallet config, it would be convenient to require the `AccountData` type to implement a given trait, like:

```rust
#[pallet::config]
pub trait Config:
    frame_system::Config<AccountData: SomeCustomTrait>
    + // other requirements
{
    // [...]
```

But this raises the error

> associated type bounds are unstable

(https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/52662)

What would be a workaround to allow this kind of behaviour until this is a stable Rust feature?

Comment: Could you explain why do you want this?

Comment: It would be to have a pallet that requires `AccountData` to implement certain trait (like a method allowing to modify the account data) without depending on a particular implementation of AccountData. This would allow to swap between multiple custom AccountData types more easily depending on runtime.